# Can I run a command with specific privileges on certain directories?

Tags: bash, permissions, files

I would like to be able to run a command, passing in parameters to bash or similar, such that this command is not allowed to write to a particular path, overriding the user's other privs.

Eg:

```
root> /bin/bash -protect /folder/to/protect mycommand.sh
```

In this example, the root user can obviously do what it wants, but while I test a new script I'm writing, I would like to protect a folder, as if the folder was read only for that user.

Is there a way to do this without adding a new user and adjusting that user's privs accordingly? It doesn't have to be in bash by the way, I don't mind the approach - as long as I can protect folders without adding a new user I don't mind!

Comment: Are we talking about subfolders too? What abouch `chmod u-w folder`, what about a backup, which you restore later?

Comment: By the way, they're called [directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28file_systems%29) in the unix world.

Answer (score 1):

Unix's security is built on permissions for users and groups. If you want to make a directory read-only for a command, you need to run it as a user who isn't allowed to write to that directory. Or there's a heavier-handed approach, which is to run the command in a virtual machine.

You may find [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/) useful. Bindfs is a stacked filesystem, that is, it creates an alternate view of a part of the directory tree. In particular, you can create a read-only view, or a view with different permissions. Bindfs can't make `/folder/to/protect` read-only, but it can create a read-only view of that directory `/read/only/view`; you need to find some other means (such as permissions) of preventing the command from writing in `/folder/to/protect.

```
bindfs --perms=a-w /folder/to/protect /read/only/view
```

Comment: Shouldn't your last sentence read "you need to find some other means (such as permissions) of preventing the command from writing in `/read/only/view"?

Comment: @Rich No, I don't think so, why should it? The read-only view is read-only to everyone. It's the folder to protect that you still need to protect, independently of the read-only view.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shared library which implemented a wrapper around `open` which performed the additional security check(s) you want.  The program you write can then use can then use `LD_PRELOAD` to load your shared library when invoking the program and override the system's `open`.

You may need to override other system calls to ensure there is not an alternative way for the program to achieve what it's trying to do.

Comment: This only works if the program is cooperative (what if it removes your wrapper? what if it has statically linked a copy of `open`? what if it calls the syscall directly?), *and* you're thorough enough (what if the program `unlink`s some files, or `rename`s them to a different directory, and so on).